# how do i apply Criteria::LIMIT for upper and lower or is there another way?

Tags: php, symfony1, propel

i have this code in indexSucces.php

```
    //some html for the main page
    <td width='48%' align='right'> 
       <?php include_partial('login', array('form' => $form)) ?>
    </td>
```

in the actions.class.php for index i have:

```
    public function executeIndex()
    {
    $this->form = new RcLoginForm();
    $this->setTemplate('index');
    $this->search_form = new RcSearchForm();
        $this->age_form = new RcAgeTableForm();
    }

    public function executeListmatches(sfWebRequest $request)
    {

    }
```

then the partial _login.php code:

```
   <form action="<?php echo url_for('password/listmatches' ) ?>"  method="post" >
   <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <span class='spn_med_lightblue_rbc'>I am a:</span>  
        <select id="gender1" name="gender1">
            <option value="male1" >Male</option>
            <option value="female1" selected="selected">Female</option>
        </select>  
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <span class='spn_med_lightblue_rbc'>Seeking a:</span>  
        <select id="gender2" name="gender2">
            <option value="male2" >Male</option>
            <option value="female2" selected="selected">Female</option>
        </select>  
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <span class='spn_med_lightblue_rbc'>Age:</span>  
        <select id="age1" name="age1">
        <?php $ages = RcAgeTablePeer::getById(18); 
            foreach ($ages as $age)
            { 
                //echo $age->getId();
                echo "<option>";
                echo $age->getId();
                echo "</option>";
            }  ?>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span class='spn_med_lightblue_rbc'>To:</span>  
        <select id="age2" name="age2">
            <?php foreach ($ages as $age)
            { 
                //echo $age->getId();
                echo "<option>";
                echo $age->getId();
                echo "</option>";
            }  ?>
        </select>  
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
    <td colspan="2">
        <span class='spn_med_lightblue_rbc'>Location:</span>  
        <select id="province" name="province">
            <option value="all" selected="selected">All</option>
            <option value="ec">Eastern Cape</option>
            <option value="nc">Northern Cape</option>
            <option value="wc">Western Cape</option>
            <option value="fs">Free State</option>
            <option value="gp">Gauteng</option>  
            <option value="kzn">Kzn</option>
            <option value="lim">Limpopo</option>
            <option value="mpu">Mpumulanga</option>  
            <option value="nw">North West</option>  
        </select>  
    </td>  
    <td><input class='submit_img' type="image" src="/images/rainbow/gobuttonbluesmall.png" value="Submit" alt="Submit"></td>
</tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
</form>
```

the above will give a home page with a section(the partial _login) that contains the login to the website and also a quick search when you hit the go button the form action will go to 
action="

this is my dilemma..i am not in any class, i just pass on the selected values through POST and use those values to get my rows

in listmatchesSuccess.php

```
   $matching_rows = RcProfileTablePeer::getAllBySelection($gender_id2,$age1,$age2,$province_id,$from,$limit);
```

where above in RcProfileTablePeer.php:

```
 static public function getAllBySelection($gender2,$age1,$age2,$province_id,$from,$limit)
{
    $criteria = new Criteria();
    $criteria->add(RcProfileTablePeer::AGE,$age1,Criteria::GREATER_EQUAL);
    $criteria->add(RcProfileTablePeer::AGE,$age2,Criteria::LESS_EQUAL);
    $criteria->add(RcProfileTablePeer::GENDER_ID,$gender2, Criteria::EQUAL);
    if ($province_id <> 10)
        $criteria->addAnd(RcProfileTablePeer::PROVINCE_ID,$province_id, Criteria::EQUAL);
    $criteria->setLimit($limit);
    return self::doSelect($criteria);
}
```

hope all this makes better sense now :)
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in your query:

```
$criteria->add(RcProfileTablePeer::AGE,$age1,Criteria::GREATER_EQUAL);
$criteria->add(RcProfileTablePeer::AGE,$age2,Criteria::LESS_EQUAL);
```

*Resulting query*: `rc_profile.age >= :age1`.

If you are looking for the objects with age between $age1 and $age2, this should do the trick:

```
$criteria->add(RcProfileTablePeer::AGE,$age1,Criteria::GREATER_EQUAL);
$criteria->addAnd(RcProfileTablePeer::AGE,$age2,Criteria::LESS_EQUAL);
```

*Resulting query*: `rc_profile.age >= :age1 AND rc_profile.age <= :age2`

Note that you should use `$criteria->addAnd` or `$criteria->addOr` to combine the conditions FOR THE SAME COLUMN.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understand what you are asking,

I you want to add a limit to your query

```
$criteria->setLimit(10);
```

and also if you want to create a pager in symfony, I would suggest the propel pager class
e.g.
    $this->page = $request->getParameter('page', 1);
    $c = new Criteria();

```
$c->add(UserPeer::Status_ID,1);

$this->pager = new sfPropelPager('User', $limit);
$this->pager->setCriteria($c));
$this->pager->setPeerMethod('doSelect');
$this->pager->setPage($this->page);
$this->pager->init();
```

You can reference this link http://www.symfony-project.org/cookbook/1_0/en/pager for more information .

I hope that answers your question;

Comment: i have posted some more code at the top...the way everything flows im not nowhere near a class so i can use $this or $request... by the time i get to the listmatches page no classes

Comment: I don't follow what you are trying to do (your listmatches action seems to be empty, but your listmatches template uses variables) but you can pass objects into your template. But you shouldn't be doing primary database fetches from the view layer.